# Is is possible to have a ever changing parameter for a Pyomo optimization (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to do an optimization of an energy system which is constituted of 2 batteries that are supposed to supply energy when a signal (a request of energy) is sent.
I have created an abstract model in Pyomo to represent my problem and so far I manage to make it work, however my problem is that my data will continuously change depending on the results of my optimization. For example if a signal is received and the batteries provide some energy then the State of Charge (SoC) will decrease (as there is less charge). I want to be able to update this value such that at the next optimization (when a successive signal comes in) my problem is solved using the real SoC.
Another way to formulate this would be: is there a way to use dataframes as input parameters to my Pyomo optimization?

This is my code. My set is called ASSETS because technically I would have multiple assets of different sorts (i.e. a classic lithium battery and maybe an hydrogen storage).

```
# iterative1.py
from pyomo.environ import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## CREATING MODEL, SET AND PARAM
model = AbstractModel()

# Sets of PTU for which the model is being created for 

# model.PTU = Set() 
model.ASSETS = Set()

# Set up the param 
model.MinPower = Param(model.ASSETS)
model.MaxPower = Param(model.ASSETS)
model.Capacity = Param(model.ASSETS)
model.SoC = Param(model.ASSETS)
model.P_rated = Param(model.ASSETS)


    # DATA FROM the EMS csv

FR = 20 #requet of power
# model.SoC = 0.9 
P_rated = 1 #how much the asset is already in use during the request of power

    # Decision variable

# model.Psh = Var(model.PTU, within=Reals)
model.Psh = Var(model.ASSETS, within=Reals)

# Objective Function

def objective_rule(model):
        return FR - sum(model.Psh[i] for i in model.ASSETS)
    
model.PowerProvided = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize)


# Constraints

        # defining the rules
        
def MinPowerRated_rule(model,i): # Min rated power limit
    return  - model.MaxPower[i] <= model.Psh[i] 

def MaxPowerRated_rule(model,i): # Max rated power limit
    return  model.Psh[i] <= model.MaxPower[i]

# def PowerRated_rule(model,i):
#     return  model.MinPower[i] <= model.Psh[i] <= model.MaxPower[i]

def MaxCapacityLimits_rule(model,i):  #Checks that the power flex is within the limits of the storage (discharge limit)
    return model.Psh[i] <= model.Capacity[i]*model.SoC[i]/4

def MinCapacityLimits_rule(model,i):  #Checks that the power flex is within the limits of the storage (charge limit)
    return model.Psh[i] >= - model.Capacity[i]*model.SoC[i]/4    

def MaxPowerAvailable_rule(model,i): 
    return model.Psh[i] <= model.MaxPower[i] - P_rated

    # return model.Psh[i] <= model.MaxPower[i] - model.P_rated[i]

def MinPowerAvailable_rule(model,i): 
    return model.Psh[i] >= - (model.MaxPower[i] - P_rated)

    # return model.Psh[i] >= - (model.MaxPower[i] - model.P_rated[i])

        # activating the constraints

model.MaxPowerRated = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MaxPowerRated_rule)
model.MinPowerRated = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MinPowerRated_rule)
model.MaxCapacityLimits = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MaxCapacityLimits_rule)
model.MinCapacityLimits = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MinCapacityLimits_rule)
model.MaxPowerAvailable = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MaxPowerAvailable_rule)
model.MinPowerAvailable = Constraint(model.ASSETS, rule=MinPowerAvailable_rule)

        #create model instance


data = DataPortal() #DataPortal handles the .dat file 
data.load(filename="abstract.dat", model=model)
instance = model.create_instance(data)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(instance)
```

and I am using the following .dat file to get the parameters for the constraints and objective function.

```
ASSETS := 1 2; 

param MinPower := 
1 0
2 0;

param MaxPower := 
1 15
2 15;

param Capacity := 
1 30
2 30; 

param SoC :=
1 0.9
2 0.9;
```

I have tried to change SoC with a dataframe that I would update after every optimization but unfortunately I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise a couple of things...

1. Switch over to a `ConcreteModel` in `pyomo`.  They are easier to deal with and you can use basic python to read data of different types (if needed) or just encode the data into the program.  It is easier to deal with and it will be more adaptable than trying to change something in an `AbstractModel` that you have loaded.
2. You model is "instantaneous" or static right now.  It does not represent the passage of time, which is fine.  So if I understand you right, some part of the input data will change and you want to re-solve with no dependency on prior solutions.  So, as a proof-of-concept, you could (a) make a concrete model, (b) get it running and QA it, (c) put it inside of a loop to solve and outside of the loop, change the input to the parameter and re-solve.

Comment: Nice, indeed maybe a ConcreteModel might be the better approach.
About the static aspect, my idea was to create a for loop for each time (every second if you prefer) where I would run the optimization, get the new SoC, change it in the param and then run it again and so on and on. I guess I could do this in the ConcreteModel too.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking around and the best way to do it is using a Dictionary.
Pyomo has some examples that can be used as a template. Inside the dictionary values of a dataframe can be directly inserted so that it creates this dynamic aspect (in the sense that the parameters will be changing according to the dataframe).
Someone else has advise to use a ConcreteModel but then you will have a very static (and very long to write) model which is not ideal (in the majority of the cases).

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are intending to do here.  You have very little data, so you could either write the dictionaries or read data from a structured file of some kind, which is fairly straightforward and put that into your ConcreteModel.  It isn't clear where/how the "new data" would arrive and, in the bigger picture, what you are trying to do with the optimization.  Perhaps work this out a little more and re-post a more focussed question

Comment: The reason why dictionary is a solution to my problem is because when I run my optimization the result affects some of the parameters that were used to run the optimization (in this case, providing power will affect the SoC of the battery). As I am trying to do an optimization that runs over a long time window, I need to be able to run my optimization multiple times (for each time interval) but also with the updated values of my parameters (new SoC). When searching online it looked a bit lengthy to modify a .dat file. Instead using a dictionary a dataframe can be used which makes it faster/ez.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).